# Installation of Git on Debian 7.4 fails

Tags: debian, git, sed

I tried to install Git (from source) on Debian 7.4, but the installation fails with the following message:

```
Writing perl.mak for Git  
Writing MYMETA.yml  
    * new perl-specific parameters  
    GEN git-add--interactive   
sed: -e expression #4, char 49: unknown option to `s'  
make: *** [git-add--interactive] Error 1
```

My sed version is 4.2.1, make is 3.81.
I have no idea what to do now, i tried with the sources of Git 1.9.1, 1.9.0 and 1.8.5.

Any ideas what else i can try?

Answer (score 2):

My version of the `sed` it also: `GNU sed version 4.2.1`. Several days ago I update my version of the Git without any problem. But I on ElementaryOS.

For install [last release](https://launchpad.net/~git-core/+archive/ppa) try to run below commands:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install git
```

And then you should have like this:

```
$ git --version 
git version 2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there something you are trying to accomplish when installing from the source, or could you simply use the package install apt-get to do it for you.

```
apt-get install git
```

Comment: The package version in the default repositories of Debian 7 is Git 1.7..., which is quite old. However, i managed to include the wheezy-backports repositories, they have Git 1.8.5.3, which is ok for me.

Comment: Oh ok, i see. There was probably a reason why its still at an old version.